# How to add a global form error to Play 2.0 form to indicate optimistic lock failure

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple model object:

```
case class Region(id: String, revision: Option[String], name: String)

object Region {        
    // Returns Some(region) if successful, None if revision doesn't match the latest
    // in the data store
    def insertOrUpdate(region: Region): Promise[Option[Region]]
}
```

In my controller I want to do something like this but I don't know how to indicate the lock failure in the response. I would like to add a global form error but can't see how from the API.

```
def update(id: String) = Action {
    implicit request => regionForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.regions.edit(formWithErrors)),        
        region => Async{
            Region.insertOrUpdate(region).map{
                _ match {
                    case None => {
                    // How do I add a global form error indicating there were server side changes detected
                        BadRequest(views.html.regions.edit(regionForm.fill(region))
                    }
                    case Some(r) => Redirect(views.html.regions.index).flashing(("success", "Update successful")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For Play 2.0.4**

A global error is in reality an error without key (see [`globalErrors`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.4/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L155) method).

There is no helper to add an error, but you can do it by yourself, with something like that:

```
regionForm.fill(region)
  .copy(errors = FormError("", "Your Error Message") +: errors)
```

**For Play 2.1**

You can use the [`withGlobalError`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L253) method:

```
regionForm.fill(region)
  .withGlobalError("Your error message")))
```